# A way to make use of form automagic for a controller without a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller without a model that handles a very cyclical task.
The user is basically filling out a form, sending it up to the server for some minor analysis, and then the server regurgitates nearly the same thing back to the user.
The user makes some adjustments, and the process starts over again.

There is nothing to save or store from this process, so it doesn't have a model.

The form i am working with has a large number of fields to deal with. Is there a way I can pass the params hash back into the view with the least amount of mess getting the fields repopulated?

Basically, I would want to tweak a couple of values in the params hash, but more or less pass the hash back so that it can repopulate the view nearly exactly how it was when it was submitted.

The old way of using OpenStruct seemed ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

In **controller action**, just initialize a variable like `@params` (or some thing like this), so that can be able to use all the values in the `params` can be available in that view page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an ActiveForm is good for your application. It use to manage (new/create/validate/...) forms with no or several models.

https://github.com/realityforge/rails-active-form